# php SoapClient I get an error "Cannot assign requested address" when doing a soap request

Tags: php, soap

I have an apache server running with PHP and I use SoapClient to call a web-service that is on the same machine (please don't ask why, it's the way I have to do it).
When I try to send a lot of these requests I get, sometimes, the error:
`SoapClient::__doRequest() [<a href='soapclient.--dorequest'>soapclient.--dorequest</a>]: connect() failed: Cannot assign requested address`
Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone cares I figured it out on my own.
We have a lot of requests going from the PHP to the soapserver (both on the same machine). There is a configuration in linux that defines how many internal ports each process can open, it is found here `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. This was set to give a range that is too small for when the PHP has a lot of load and thus we didn't have enough internal ports left to open more connections and got the error message.